# Jira: can we switch off the 'smart' date display, such as "xx hours ago"

Tags: date, configuration, jira

I find it very annoying, if it is a date field, I want to see a date. "1 hour ago" is sometimes not granular enough, if you are disputing response/resolution times with customers.
Is it configurable in Jira?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jira Server or Jira Data Center, you can do this by setting the `jira.lf.date.relativize` property to `false` in `jira-config.properties` (see the [Jira documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/display-standard-dates-in-jira-server-414187622.html)).

I'm not aware of a way to reconfigure this setting with Jira Cloud. However, regardless of your Jira platform (meaning all of Jira Server/DC/Cloud), when you see a relative date, you can typically hover the mouse pointer over the date for a while and the full date/time will appear in a tooltip.